# Why would Nginx serve files correctly from the default directory but not new directory?

Tags: nginx, centos

**Installation**

**OS**: CentOS 7.4

**Server**: Nginx 1.12.2

---

**Question:** My nginx installation serves files without problem from the default directory, `/usr/share/nginx/html`.  Unfortunately I get a 403 error when I use a new folder that I created, `/www/html`.  What should I look for?

My permissions are identical for both folders although the owner is different.

**Original default folder**

`drwxr-xr-x.   13 root  root         155 Jan  8 09:25 usr`

**New default folder**

`drwxr-xr-x.   3 first first         18 Jan 15 10:45 www`

I am using the stripped down `server.conf` file below and it works correctly.

```
events {}

http {

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  mydomain.com;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

However when I change `server.conf` to use this directory `/www/html` I get a 403 error.

Thanks for any help in advance!  I'm a noob and not even sure where to look beyond file permissions.

Comment: Most probably your nginx is running with root user and it needs the same user to have permission on `/www` and `/www/html`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.

Solution. You must create test.example.com.conf **inside** the conf.d folder

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/test.example.com.conf
```

And the file :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    #listen       *:80;
    server_name  test.example.com;

    # note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
    root   /var/www/test.example.com/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # Remove trailing slash to please routing system.
    if (!-d $request_filename) {
            rewrite     ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

restart server `systemctl restart nginx.service`